# Customize which flex items that are allowed the expand one row in a flex matrix

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a matrix (or table if you will) using flex. I want to have rows with headers of two kinds.

1. No wrap headers should never wrap and cut text with an **ellipsis**.
2. Careful wrappers that do not expand their row, but can wrap if the other cells expand the row. These would wrap **as much as they can**, and then cut the rest of with an **ellipsis**.

It is the second one that I have not figured out how to achieve. I have looked at some flex properties that sounded as they might take my closer to the effect that I want. These did not work, but I have included them as comments in the corresponding class.

[Brief example with the markup and styling that I have now.](http://jsfiddle.net/sh35jwtd/22/)

Looking for solutions without JS, as I'd probably rather settle with having every header row  with no wrapping than add a bunch of code. If you do suggest code to fix this, I will of course still have a look at it.

HTML

```css
.matrix {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: min-content;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.cell {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.no-wrap {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  hyphens: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.careful-wrapper {
  /* flex-basis: fill; */
  /* flex: initial; */
}

.expander {
  text-overflow: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="matrix">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="no-wrap cell">My text should never wrap, no matter the sibling</div>
    <div class="expander cell">My content should wrap lines and therefor allow as many line-breaks to my sibling</div>
    <div class="expander cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="careful-wrapper cell">My text-should only wrap if my sibling divs expand the row. To see the effect my content needs to be longer than my siblings, excuse my rambling</div>
    <div class="expander cell"></div>
    <div class="expander cell">My content should wrap lines and therefor allow as many line-breaks to my sibling</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sh35jwtd/22/)

Comment: I'm really confused about what you expect this to look like. Can you post an image of the *expected* result. Frankly though, if you want a table, why not use one?

Comment: @Paulie_D It's because of the way it's generated and because everything should be responsive.